# How can I add borders in Excel file using VBScript 6.0?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vb6, export

I want to add difference borders in Excel file, but this codes don't work:

1 - With this code Excel file is the same without borders and show error "planned an already existing variable"

```
Dim app As Object
Dim bookAs Object
Dim sheetAs Object
app= CreateObject("Excel.Application")
book= app.Workbooks.Add
sheet= book.Worksheets(1)
sheet.Range("A1:F20").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

2 - While this code, show error "planned an already existing variable"

```
Dim app As Object
Dim bookAs Object
Dim sheetAs Object
app= CreateObject("Excel.Application")
book= app.Workbooks.Add
sheet= book.Worksheets(1)
With sheet.Range("A:X").Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
```

Have you any ideas about to resolve and add borders in Excel file?

Thanks!

Comment: Dim bookAs Object
Dim sheetAs Object    should be  " As"

Answer (score 1):

You are using late binding so presumably have not added a reference to Excel's automation library, this means constants like `xlContinuous` are all undefined.

Lookup the value in Excel (Ctrl+G in the VBA Editor, type `?xlContinuous`) and define a const for them at the top of your VB6 module:

```
Private Const xlContinuous As Long = 1
```

You should also use `set` when assigning object references:

```
set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
set book = app.Workbooks.Add
set sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Unfortunately, there are no useful error messages in the interpreter about the lack of constants, so you have to know it beforehand. The reference to other differences between VBA and VBScript may also be of help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970436.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've always used it like this....

```
Dim rng as Range

Set rng = xlSheet.Range(***specify your range here***)
    rng.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```